# Memory leak on repeated connection/disconnection with reactivesockets

Tags: c#, sockets, memory-leaks, reactive-programming, rx.net

I am using a reactivesockets library I found in GitHub (https://github.com/clariuslabs/reactivesockets) and I was wondering if somebody has experienced a memory leak when clients connect and disconnect.

I am running the ReactiveServer sample provided with the library, which basically consists of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var port = 1055;
  if (args.Length > 0)
    port = int.Parse(args[0]);

  var server = new ReactiveListener(port);

  server.Connections.Subscribe(socket =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("New socket connected {0}", socket.GetHashCode());

    var protocol = new StringChannel(socket);

    // Here we hook the "echo" prototocol
    protocol.Receiver.Subscribe(
      s => { Console.Write(s); protocol.SendAsync(s).Wait(); }, 
      e => Console.WriteLine(e),
      () => Console.WriteLine("Socket receiver completed"));

    socket.Disconnected += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Socket disconnected {0}", sender.GetHashCode());
    socket.Disposed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Socket disposed {0}", sender.GetHashCode());
  });

  server.Start();

  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then I created a console application with a loop and within this loop a ReactiveClient is created, then connects to the server, waits 200 ms and then disconnects. The client does not send any data to the server. This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var numberOfClients = 1000;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++) {
    var controlClient = new ReactiveClient("127.0.0.1", 1055);
    controlClient.ConnectAsync().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Connect");
    Task.Delay(200).Wait();
    controlClient.Disconnect();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Disconnect");
  }
}
```

What I see in the memory profiler of Visual Studio is that the memory usage of the server grows linearly when I run my test application. When the test application stops, the memory usage of the server does not drop; it stays at whatever level it reached.

The memory leak does not seem to happen (or at least not so clearly, with linear growth of memory usage) when I run the ReactiveServer sample without the code that instantiates the StringChannel class and subscribes to the Receiver. The code would be like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var port = 1055;
  if (args.Length > 0)
      port = int.Parse(args[0]);

  var server = new ReactiveListener(port);

  server.Connections.Subscribe(socket =>
  {
      Console.WriteLine("New socket connected {0}", socket.GetHashCode());
  });

  server.Start();

  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For that reason, I was suspecting that the memory leak could be related to the fact that the subscription to the Receiver of the protocol (when doing `protocol.Receiver.Subscribe`) is not properly disposed when the client disconnects. Reading more in detail about Rx.NET, I have read that in normal circumstances (if the observable sequence finishes), then the subscription is automatically disposed, but if the sequence does not complete, then it is not disposed. I suspect that the sequence does not complete when the client disconnects and then the subscription is not disposed. I have tried to dispose the subscription in the Disconnected event handler, but I did not see any noticeable improvement.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not solve the memory leak, so I decided to replace the library. I am now using [SuperSocket](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket) and it works really well. No memory problems at all.

Comment: i am using super socket for me memory on server is not decreasing event after disconnecting client any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `controlClient.dispose();` after you disconnect.

This will release any operating resources used by that object.

To make it read better I would try wrapping the controlClient in a using block.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var numberOfClients = 1000;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++) {
    using{var controlClient = new ReactiveClient("127.0.0.1", 1055)) 
    {
       controlClient.ConnectAsync().Wait();
       Console.WriteLine(@"Connect");
       Task.Delay(200).Wait();
       controlClient.Disconnect();
       Console.WriteLine(@"Disconnect");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right: the control client should be disposed. However, the memory leak is in the server, so I don't see any improvement there because of this fix.